# JSFiddle JavaScript not working in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

I made a little project for school in JSFiddle, transferred the code to Dreamweaver and it ceased to function. Here is my code in JSFiddle, under the HTML section as it was the only place it would work.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <select name="metal" id="metal">
                    <option value="9CaratGold">9 Carat Gold.</option>
                    <option value="18CaratGold">18 Carat Gold.</option>
                    <option value="Silver">Silver.</option>
                    <option value="Platinum">Platinum.</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                <select name="currency" id="currency">
                    <option value="GBP">GBP (£)</option>
                    <option value="EUR">EUR (€)</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD ($)</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input maxlength="6" type="number" name="weight" id="weight" style="width:185px;" value="Insert weight (g)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="calcButton" id="calcButton" onClick="calcPrices()" value="Get a Quote">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p id="quotation"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data;
    csv = "9 Carat Gold,18 Carat Gold,Silver,Platinum\n11.87,23.73,0.49,27.52",
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/echo/html/",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                html: csv
            },
            success: function(data) {
                processData(data);
            }
        });
    });

    function processData(allText) {
        var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
        lines = [];

        for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
            if (data.length == headers.length) {

                var tarr = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                    tarr.push(headers[j] + ":" + data[j]);
                }
                lines.push(tarr);
            }
        }
    }

    function calcPrices() {

        var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
        var metal = document.getElementById('metal').value;
        var currency = document.getElementById('currency').value;
        var metalPrice;
        var totalPrice;
        var conversionRate;
        var conversionSymbol;

        if (metal === "9CaratGold") {
            metalPrice = data[0];
        }

        if (metal === "18CaratGold") {
            metalPrice = data[1];
        }

        if (metal === "Silver") {
            metalPrice = data[2];
        }

        if (metal === "Platinum") {
            metalPrice = data[3];
        }

        if (currency === "USD") {
            conversionRate = 1.57;
            conversionSymbol = "$";
        }

        if (currency === "EUR") {
            conversionRate = 1.23;
            conversionSymbol = "€";
        }

        if (currency === "GBP") {
            conversionRate = 1.00;
            conversionSymbol = "£";
        }

        totalPrice = ((metalPrice) * (conversionRate));
        totalPrice = ((totalPrice) * (weight));
        totalPrice = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
        if (weight <= 500 && weight >= 1) {
            document.getElementById("quotation").style.color = "black"
            document.getElementById("quotation").innerHTML = (('We can offer you ' + (conversionSymbol + totalPrice)) + ' for ' + weight + 'g.');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("quotation").style.color = "red"
            document.getElementById("quotation").innerHTML = "Please insert a weight between 500 and 1 gram.";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the JSFiddle for reference. http://jsfiddle.net/KieranOM/u3kxomaa/
On the JSFiddle, the button works perfectly; however locally it does nothing when clicked.

Here is some key information. In both JSFiddle and Dreamweaver I have jQuery 1.8.3 enabled. In JSFiddle, I have disabled the onLoad and instead changed it to

> no wrap - in

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the server set up to actually return data back like they do?

```
url: "/echo/html/",
```

That needs to be hooked up to your actual serverside page that is returning the value...

---

Also you do not cancel the form submission with the button click. Return false to stop the action.

```
onClick="calcPrices(); return false"
```

You really should not use inline events.

```
$("#calcButton").on("click, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calcPrices();
});
```

Comment: Would you mind sectioning out what you are referencing to? I cannot see a form within my code. Thank you in advance :)
EDIT:
Sorry about this but I am relatively new to how JSFiddle works, would you mind helping me into correcting the code to work locally?

Comment: You do not see the click event on your button?

Comment: I see the event but I was not sure what you were meaning by the "form." I originally only used the "function calcPrices()" downwards, but I introduced the CSV parsing to work along side it. The original version worked fine as it was, everything within the script above "function calcPrices()" is newly added, so I am not too familiar with it

Comment: What is the error you are getting? did you add the return false?

Comment: I am receiving two errors, one with 'onClick="calcPrices();' and the second with 'metalPrice = data[0];'
They are classed under the same error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
I have also realised my fault with "url: "/echo/html/"," and replaced it with "url: "metals.csv"," as well as removing "data: { html: csv }," any thought on what to do next?
UPDATE: There is also an "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///X:XXX/XXX/metals.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extention-resource" with jquery.

Comment: _Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http_. This indicates that you are running the page as either `c:/` or `file:/` and not under the `http` protocol. To do that, you will need a localhost/local server running.

Comment: @GVashist thank you so much, I feel like such an idiot after re-reading that once I read your comment. Thank you to the both of you for helping me fix it! It is honestly greatly appreciated! I can finally hand in my Computer Science coursework! :D